# My ImageButton isn't rescaling like the code is telling it to. Infact it's not doing anything

Tags: java, android

My ImageButton isn't rescaling like the code is telling it to. Infact it's not doing anything.

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    setTitle("Valour");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
    getScreenRes();
}

public void getScreenRes() {
    DisplayMetrics display = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = display.widthPixels;
    int height = display.heightPixels;
    int buttonheight = display.heightPixels / 8;
    double buttonwidth = buttonheight * 2.66666667;
    int buttonwidthint = (int) Math.round(buttonwidth);
    ImageButton firsttimeFB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.firsttime_fb);
    firsttimeFB.getLayoutParams().width = buttonwidthint;
    firsttimeFB.getLayoutParams().height = buttonheight;
}
```

XML:

```xml
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="@drawable/facebook"
    android:id="@+id/firsttime_fb"
/>
```

And it ends up looking like this:

[image: Incorrectly scaled ImageButton]

Comment: Replace android:background with android:src

Comment: im always told to do the opposite

Comment: same thing, only difference is the image isnt fit to the imagebutton width/height (and i want that to fit)

Comment: What actually are you trying to do?

Comment: want buttons to be 1/8th the size of the screen in height, then adjust the width by 2.6667xHeight since the width:height ratio of the image is 2.666667.

Answer (score 0):

call `setLayoutParams()` from the `firsttimeFB` after change the width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Try using android:src and change the ScaleType, see if that makes it scale better.
Also after setting the width and hight by calling getLayoutParams() you should call request layout or the changes will not be displayed.

If you want to set the width based on the height or vice versa you should create your own custom ImageButton class which contains the following code:

```
public class CustomImageButton extends ImageButton{

...

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

int height = getMeasuredHeight();
float constant = 2.6666;
setMeasuredDimension(height * constant, height);
}

 ...

}
```

What I want to add is that I am wondering what you are trying to do. I can not think of a senario in which I need the screensize to determen the size of the button. Try to rethink your approach and ask yourself if what you are doing is making any sense.

Comment: Yes, I didn't understand what he is trying to do too.

Comment: I want buttons to be 1/8th the size of the screen in height, then adjust the width by 2.6667xHeight since the width:height ratio of the image is 2.666667. can't change code now but will try this tomorrow, thanks

Comment: `public class CustomImageButton extends ImageButton{` is giving me "There is no default constructor avaliable in 'android.view.ImageButton'

Comment: You have to add the constructors, go to the error and hit alt-enter in android studio then the solution should come up. You can also add      '       public CustomImageButton(Context context) {
              super(context);
        }

        public CustomImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
           }'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void getScreenRes(){
    DisplayMetrics display = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = display.widthPixels;
    int height = display.heightPixels;
    int buttonheight = display.heightPixels / 8;
    double buttonwidth = buttonheight * 2.66666667;
    int buttonwidthint = (int) Math.round(buttonwidth);
    ImageButton firsttimeFB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.firsttime_fb);
    LayoutParams lp = firsttimeFB.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = buttonwidthint;
    lp.height = buttonheight;
    firsttimeFB.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

}